# ANDROID:: Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: android

***I am trying to compile a simple project*** :: I am getting errors

```
[2014-02-13 22:28:38 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-02-13 22:28:38 - MyAndroidApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

**I have tried to debug these steps**::

- I have cleaned the project & ran it .... no changes !
- I have the Buildpath snapshot below

[image]

**Note**::I have checked answers for this in stackoverflow, but i couldnt resolve this from the solutions i found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I solved my situation with this:

Downgrading the [build tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html):

http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/how-to-solve-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-for-stack-trace/

- **But now i have updated and this issue is fixed with** [**build tools 19.0.1**](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html):

**Build Tools, Revision 19.0.1 (December 2013)**

> Fixed miscellaneous build issues: Fixed support for compiling
>    RenderScript in NDK mode with Gradle.
>   **Fixed BufferOverflowException problem in the dx build. (Issue 61710)**

if you have problemas, look into your AndroidManifest.xml and the value of `android:targetSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml` must match with `target=android-[value]` in project.properties.

Comment: Thank you very much ..... Updating  build tools 19.0.1 solved my problem :)